# Cannot access this.draw() using ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I'm trying to make a button refresh a window, but I get this error message:

```
Test.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
                    this.draw();
                        ^
  symbol: method draw()
1 error
```

This is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Test {
    JFrame frame;

    public void createMainWindow() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800,600);
        JButton refresh = new JButton("Refresh");
        refresh.setBounds(620, 20, 100, 30);
        refresh.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    this.draw();
                }
            }
            );
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.add(refresh);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setTitle("Title");
    }

    public void draw() {
        // Code                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I have obviously misunderstood something about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.draw();
```

Refers to the ActionListner.

You want:

```
Test.this.draw();
```

to refer to a method in the Test class.

Answer (score 1):

When you created an explicit anonymous class, `this` refers to the instance of the `ActionListener`. To draw the outer class, use `Test.this.draw()`, or, more simply, replace your whole listener with a lambda (which technically creates an anonymous class but doesn't take over `this`):

```
refresh.addActionListener(e -> this.draw());
```